# Data structure with fast sorted insertion, sorted deletion and lookup

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I'm looking for a very specific data structure. Suppose the maximum number of elements is known. All elements are integers. Duplicates are allowed. 
The operations are:

Look up. If I inserted n elements, `a[0]` is the smallest elements, `a[a.length - 1]` is the highest. `a[k]` is the k smallest element. Required runtime: `O(1)`

Insertion. Does a sorted insertion, `insert(b)` where `b` is an integer. Required runtime: `O(log n)`

Deletion. `delete(i)` deletes the ith element. Required runtime: `O(log n)`

I want  kind of data structure is this? My question is language independent, but I'm coding in C++.

Comment: In general, I think you're looking for a *priority queue*, with the exception of having a known maximum. There are a ton of ways to get this through STL or your own pet implementations.

Comment: @jhill515 priority queue doesn't have `O(1)` look up does it? so `a[k]` is the k smallest element.

Comment: Do you need `O(1)` access for all `k`, not just `0` and `length - 1`?

Comment: @jhill515 there are 2 problem with queues: **1** - it, by design, provides access only to the top element. **2** - it's usually implemented as optimised binary tree (red-black or AVL), which (if you could achieve it) would require `log_n` time to access `k`-th element.

Comment: @Evg Yes, for all of them.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard about data structure with `O(1)` lookup and `O(log n)` insertion/deletion. *It's just too good to be true.* All data structures have trade-offs in some operations to achieve best results in others. Closest would be [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), with `O(1)` lookup of smallest element only (rest is `O(n)`) and logarithmic insert/delete. `std::priority_queue` is an implementation of one, as mentioned above.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen good call to mention trade-offs regarding different data structures. I also believe an optimised binary heap would be the closest, but still it wouldn't meet all the requirements.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen this is true if I wanted all operations to be `O(1)`. Actually, with the comparison paradigm it's impossible, since it implies that sorting is `O(n)`, which can't exist with a comparator (but you can do it with a radix). My constraints I don't believe are violating any theorem.

Comment: @SpentDeath radix sort changes nothing here, unfortunately. The problem is to insert an element between elements that are contiguous in memory (requirement for true O(1) indexing), and that's not possible in less than `O(n)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe such data structure does not exist. Constant lookup for any element (e.g. indexing) requires contiguous memory, which makes insertion impossible to do in less than `O(n)` if you want to keep the range sorted.

There are arguments for hash tables and wrappers around hash tables, but there are two things to keep in mind when mentioning them:

- Hash tables have average access (insertion, deletion, find) in `O(1)`, but that assumes very few hash collisions. If you wish to meet the requirements in regard to pessimistic complexities, hash tables are out of the quesion since their pessimistic access time is `O(n)`.
- Hash tables are, by their nature, *unordered*. They, most of the time, do have internal arrays for storing (for example) buckets of data, but the elements themselves are neither all in contiguous memory nor ordered by some property (other than maybe modulo of their hash, which itself should produce very different values for *similar* objects).

To not leave you empty handed - if you wish to get as close to your requirements as possible, you need to specify which complexities would you sacrifice to achieve the others. I'd like to propose either `std::priority_queue` or `std::multiset`.

- `std::priority_queue` provides access only to the top element - it is guaranteed that it will be either the smallest or the greatest (depending on the comparator you use to specify the relation) element in the collection. Insertion and deletion are both achieved in `O(log_n)` time.
- `std::multiset`* provides access to every element inside it, but at a higher cost - `O(log_n)`. It also achieves `O(log_n)` in insertion and deletion.

---

*<sub>Careful - do not confuse with `std::set`, which does not allow for duplicate elements.</sub>

Comment: Is it possible to design a container with these requirements? Or is it theoretically not possible?

Comment: I believe it's theoretically not possible, but I don't have any mathematical proof. I could try to calculate something by extending the proof that you can't sort in better time than `O(log_n)` if you use comparisons, but I am not that good at that.